# UFT not recognizing controls in Microsoft Management Console App

Tags: hp-uft, mmc

I am evaluating UFT (formerly QTP) as an automation tool for testing a Microsoft Management Console app.  The controls have the prefix MMC, e.g. MMCMainWindow.

I have contacted HP and so far they have not come up with a solution.  The solutions architect I am working with suggested using the extensibility toolkit, but I'm not sure that was meant for creating custom controls for an entire application.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a "standard" Snap-in or custom? Can you give us the name, eg "Device Manger", "Active X control" or "IP Security Monitor"?

Comment: http://community.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/UI-Automation-and-HPE-UFT-Expanding-UFT-s-Testing-Abilities/ba-p/6832642#.VtU5_0a-YyI announces that UFT now supports "the" standard UI automation interface of Microsoft's. If MS supports that in the management console app, this would be the way to go, making UFT completely compatible with that app.